# Fixing the error: Creation of the private accessor for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TypesAndSymbols.Assembly' failed

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I'm creating unit tests for a Windows Forms application.  One of my methods is an event-handler for a form (I don't know if this is the source of my problem):

```
private void ImportButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // blah blah
}
```

Now when I attempt to create a unit test for this method via right-clicking the source ->  "Create Unit Tests" everything seems to work fine until I open the generated unit test code:

```
/// <summary>
///A test for ImportButton_Click
///</summary>
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("FooBar.exe")]
public void ImportButton_ClickTest()
{
    // Creation of the private accessor for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TypesAndSymbols.Assembly' failed
    Assert.Inconclusive("Creation of the private accessor for \'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TypesAndSy" +
            "mbols.Assembly\' failed");
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  I found this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/1a5666d7-a745-4258-8f21-567dc79c0574/) that details the a similar issue which I don't think applies to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in VS2008 that they never bothered to resolve... :(

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/365058

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed more or less in VS2010 SP1, but the issue popped up again today. The assembly I was creating a test for contained covariant generic interfaces. The accessor builder didn't like that. Removing the "in" directives solved the problem and I could live with my interfaces not being covariant for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Unit tests project, since, there were only couple of classes and added a new project with new set of files, and it worked. I was able to generate accessors for testing private methods too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, you should build your project to generate the DLL required by the accessor and then create the unit test for the private function, It will work.